# delete image from folder using php ,js this is my code i getting succseful message but not actually get delete

Tags: javascript, php

html Code

```
<input type="hidden" value="'.$image.'" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />
<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/>

<div class= "buttondel">

    <button class="button6" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: 25px; margin:-9px -5px;"></i></button>
</div>
```

js function:

```
function delete_image()
{
    var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  

    if(status==true) {
        var file = $("#delete_file").val();
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"php/del.php",
                data:{file:file},
                success(html){
                    alert('Deleted');
                }
        });
    }
}
```

**Php code:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $filename = $_POST['file'];
    unlink($filename);
    echo"done";
}
?>
```

Comment: is your file stores parellel to the `del.php` file ?

Comment: Show us what is in `$image` please

Comment: What is the contents of $filename when it reaches the Php code?  Does that match the file path and filename you think you are deleting?

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is not wrapped in single quotes and `echo`ed like:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$image.'" name="delete_file" id="delete_file" />
<input type="button" value="Delete image" onclick="delete_image()"/>
<div class= "buttondel">
    <button class="button6" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="font-size: 25px; margin:-9px -5px;"></i></button>
</div>';
```

The value of `'.$image.'` will be a string literal and not the value of the variable.

> You should also be careful of your PHP code as one could manipulate
>   the `POST` request and delete your files.

But ignoring that and if you are indeed echoing out a path to the file.

You should then do some basic sanity checking in the PHP code.

```
<?php
// enable error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $filename = $_POST['file'];
    if (!file_exists($filename)) {
        die('File does not exist!');
    }

    //
    if (!is_writable($filename)) {
        die('Wont be able to delete file!');
    } elseif(!unlink($filename)) {
        die('Could not delete file!');
    }

    echo "Deleted";
}
?>
```

The issue is **most likely** the javascript success callback `success(html) {` breaking your js code (check console), it should be like:

```
function delete_image()
{
    var status = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete ?");  

    if(status==true) {
        var file = $("#delete_file").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "php/del.php",
          data: {file:file},
          success: function (html) {
             alert(html); // maybe something better..
          },
          // this would help you debug it too
          error: function (jqXHR, error) {
             alert('Error:' + jqXHR.status + ' - ' + error);
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you don't check the return value of `unlink`.
I returns a boolean value as simply described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp).

Second, make sure you give the real file path to unlink.

Comment: If you think about it, this is really only a comment